# Отсортировать лексикографически

Tags: c

Есть числа. Пусть это числа 102 211 121 010(Все числа одного размера N. В данном примере N=3) В массиве они записаны следующим образом 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 0.  Нужно их отсортировать лексикографически в этом массиве. (010 102 121 211) То есть записать так 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 1 2 1 1.

Comment: См. `man strncmp` и `man qsort`.

Comment: Да, но у меня сами числа записаны в массив в виде цифр этого числа.

Comment: Банально переписать в строки (`str[i] = int_array[j] + '0'`) или вручную реализовать сортировку, сравнивая поэлементно.

Comment: для меня это все что-то новое, сейчас попробую. мне нужно из массива 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 с шагом в N записать в строки 102 211 121 010 и применить strncmp ?

Comment: @Руслан Лутфуллин, а в чем проблема?

    int compar(const void *a, const void *b);

    int main() {
      char a[] = "123456999789012";
      
      puts(a);
      qsort(a, strlen(a) / 3, 3, compar);
      return puts(a) == EOF;
    }

Ну, а функцию `compar()`, вызывающую `strncmp()` уж сами постарайтесь (почитайте в книжке о приведении типов (особенно указателей)).

Comment: Ничего не понял :(
Пусть есть массив final_answer[]={1, 0, 2, 2 ,1, 1 ,1, 2, 1, 0, 1 ,0} и длина числа: N=3.
Мне нужно записать в массив str[]={'102',211',121', 010'} и как-то отсортировать этот массив лексикографически.

Comment: У Вас есть массив (он же строка) с символами (цифрами). Сортируете (меняете их местами, точнее это за Вас делает qsort) тройки символов по месту.

Для сравнения троек по адресам x и y вызывайте `strncmp(x, y, 3)`.

Вот и все.

--

Вы про qsort-то прочитали?

--

Если я неправильно понял вопрос и у Вас цифры *не символы ascii*, а байты с кодами цифр (т.е. в т.ч. и двоичный 0), то вместо strncmp вызывайте memcmp(). Вообще-то ее можно в любом случае использовать.

Только, если в массиве есть двоичные нули, то и strlen(a) / 3 не годится. Вместо strlen Вы должны известную Вам длину массива взять.